# Need help with long and wide table; tried longtabu, longtable, sidewaystable and nothing seems to fit!

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx, tabu

I've literally been spending hours, trying to fit this long and wide table with a series of packages: tabu, longtabu, tabularx, sidewaystable, but nothing seems to fit.
This is for a thesis so I rather prefer not to use sidewaystable ... only it is really not readable in any other way.

Can someone help me with this:

```
\begin{sidewaystable}[!ht]
\medskip
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\tabcolsep=2pt
  \centering
   \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXXX}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Descrição da variável explicativa}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Significado dos valores para variáveis binárias}} & \textbf{Atributo correspondente} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Feature class em que entra}} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{$F_{Tit}$=Tráfego de entrada em veículos por dia (TMDA) para a intersecção i e ano t} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{N.A.} & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{TMDA} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Nós} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{$F_{Ti}$=Tráfego, em veículos por dia (TMDA) nos dois sentidos de circulação do segmento i} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{N.A.} &    & Arcos \\
    $LB_i$=Equilíbrio de vias na interseção i (i.e., nº igual de vias em todos os ramos de entrada) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0 - não} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{LB} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{Nós } \\
       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1 - sim} &    &  \\
    $LEG_i$ =Número de ramos de entrada da interseção/ rotunda i & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0 - 3 ramos} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{LEGS} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{Nós } \\
       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1 - 4 ramos} &    &  \\
    $LMAJT7_i$=Número de vias na direção principal da interseção i é igual a 3 ou superior & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0 - não} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{LMAJ} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{Nós } \\
       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1 - sim} &    &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{$LOW_i$ =Número de ramos com sentido de circulação único na intersecção i} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{N.A.} & LOW & Nós \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{$LWMAJ_i$=Largura média das vias de entrada na direcção principal na intersecção i(m)} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{N.A.} & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{LW} & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{Nós } \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{$LWMINJ_i$=Largura média das vias de entrada na direcção secundária na intersecção i(m)} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{N.A.} &    &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{$L_i$ =Comprimento total do segento i (m)} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{N.A.} & \textit{Shape\_length} & Arcos \\
    $MMAJ_i$=Presença de separador central nos dois ramos da direcção principal i & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0 - não} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{N.D.} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{N.D.} \\
       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1 - sim} &    &  \\
    $NLANES4_i$=Número total de vias igual ou superior a 4 para o segmento i & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0 - não} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{NLANES4} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{Arcos} \\
       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1 - sim} &    &  \\
    $RTPMAJ_i$=Presença de vias exclusivas de viragem à direita na direcção principal na intersecção i & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multirow{4}[3]{*}{RTP} & \multirow{4}[3]{*}{Nós} \\
       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0 - não} &    &  \\
    $RTPMIN_i$=Presença de vias exclusivas de viragem à direita na secundária principal na intersecção i & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1 - sim} &    &  \\
       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &    &  \\
    $TCD_i$=Sistema de controlo de tráfego na intersecção i & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0 - não} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{TCD} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{Nós } \\
       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1 - sim} &    &  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}%
    }
   \caption{Correspondência entre variáveis explicativas e atributos nas entidades geográficas.}   
  \label{tab:vars}%
\end{sidewaystable}%
```

To look more like this -> http://d.pr/f/SxgX

Answer (score 4):

Your main error was using `\multicolumn{1}{l}` everywhere which forces `l` setting which is always one line.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}
\vspace*{-50pt}
\centering
\hspace*{-1cm}\begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\textwidth+2cm}{Xlll}
    \toprule
\centering \textbf{Descrição da variável explicativa} &
\multicolumn{1}{p{3cm}}{\centering\textbf{Significado dos valores para variáveis binárias}}&
\multicolumn{1}{p{2cm}}{\centering\textbf{Atributo correspondente}} &
\multicolumn{1}{p{2cm}}{\centering \textbf{Feature class em que entra}}\\
   \midrule
    {$F_{Tit}$=Tráfego de entrada em veículos por dia (TMDA) para a intersecção i e ano t} & {N.A.} & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{TMDA} & {Nós} \\
    {$F_{Ti}$=Tráfego, em veículos por dia (TMDA) nos dois sentidos de circulação do segmento i} & {N.A.} &    & Arcos \\
   $LB_i$=Equilíbrio de vias na interseção i (i.e., nº igual de vias em todos os ramos de entrada) & {0 - não} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{LB} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{Nós } \\
       & {1 - sim} &    &  \\
    $LEG_i$ =Número de ramos de entrada da interseção/ rotunda i & {0 - 3 ramos} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{LEGS} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{Nós } \\
       & {1 - 4 ramos} &    &  \\
    $LMAJT7_i$=Número de vias na direção principal da interseção i é igual a 3 ou superior & {0 - não} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{LMAJ} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{Nós } \\
       & {1 - sim} &    &  \\
    {$LOW_i$ =Número de ramos com sentido de circulação único na intersecção i} & {N.A.} & LOW & Nós \\
    {$LWMAJ_i$=Largura média das vias de entrada na direcção principal na intersecção i(m)} & {N.A.} & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{LW} & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{Nós } \\
    {$LWMINJ_i$=Largura média das vias de entrada na direcção secundária na intersecção i(m)} & {N.A.} &    &  \\
    {$L_i$ =Comprimento total do segento i (m)} & {N.A.} & \textit{Shape\_length} & Arcos \\
    $MMAJ_i$=Presença de separador central nos dois ramos da direcção principal i & {0 - não} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{N.D.} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{N.D.} \\
       & {1 - sim} &    &  \\
    $NLANES4_i$=Número total de vias igual ou superior a 4 para o segmento i & {0 - não} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{NLANES4} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{Arcos} \\
       & {1 - sim} &    &  \\
    $RTPMAJ_i$=Presença de vias exclusivas de viragem à direita na direcção principal na intersecção i & {} & \multirow{4}[3]{*}{RTP} & \multirow{4}[3]{*}{Nós} \\
       & {0 - não} &    &  \\
    $RTPMIN_i$=Presença de vias exclusivas de viragem à direita na secundária principal na intersecção i & {1 - sim} &    &  \\
       & {} &    &  \\
    $TCD_i$=Sistema de controlo de tráfego na intersecção i & {0 - não} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{TCD} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{Nós } \\
       & {1 - sim} &    &  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}\hspace*{-1cm}%

   \caption{Correspondência entre variáveis explicativas e atributos nas entidades geográficas.}   
  \label{tab:vars}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, thank you, this is much better, but didn't solve the entire problem, because I'm writing a thesis and the margins are considerably large. This table in particular takes the whole page and we can even see the Title and page number (39) as can be seen here: http://d.pr/f/ANfh. Is there a way to convert this to a longtable or something similar, instead of resizing?

Comment: @neverMind yes now it is in that form it is easy to change to longtable,  just change the two `X` to (say) p{5cm} and remove the `table` and change from tabularx to longtable, and it should work without problem. Note most of the width of the later columns is in the heading, I can't read the text but if you could make that shorter, it would be a lot simpler.

Comment: Ok, fortunatelly I can remove 2 lines that don't belong to that table, but I'm certain I will have a longtable or two later. I explored a bit and made my changes. Thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @David Carlisle answers, I decided to remove 2 lines of my table (I was lucky that they didn't belong there) and obtain the final output as :

```
\begin{table}
%\vspace*{-15pt}
\centering
\hspace*{-1cm}
\begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\textwidth+2cm}{Xll}
    \toprule
\centering \textbf{Variável explicativa} &
\multicolumn{1}{p{1.4cm}}{\centering\textbf{Valor}} &
\multicolumn{1}{p{1.7cm}}{\centering\textbf{Atributo}}\\
%\multicolumn{1}{p{2cm}}{\centering \textbf{Feature class em que entra}}\\
   \midrule
$F_{Tit}$=Tráfego de entrada em veículos por dia (TMDA) para a intersecção \textit{i} e ano t & {N.A.}  & TMDA\\
%    {$F_{Ti}$=Tráfego, em veículos por dia (TMDA) nos dois sentidos de circulação do segmento \textit{i}} & {N.A.} &    & Arcos \\
   \midrule
 $LB_i$=Equilíbrio de vias na interseção \textit{i} (i.e., nº igual de vias em todos os ramos de entrada) & {0 - não} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{LB}\\
 & {1 - sim} & \\
    \midrule
 $LEG_i$ =Número de ramos de entrada da interseção/ rotunda \textit{i} & {0 - 3 ramos} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{LEGS} \\
 & {1 - 4 ramos} & \\
    \midrule
 $LMAJT7_i$=Número de vias na direção principal da interseção \textit{i} é igual a 3 ou superior & {0 - não} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{LMAJ} \\
  & {1 - sim} & \\
     \midrule
$LOW_i$ =Número de ramos com sentido de circulação único na intersecção \textit{i} & {N.A.} & LOW \\
  \midrule
 {$LWMAJ_i$=Largura média das vias de entrada na direcção principal na intersecção \textit{i} (m)} & {N.A.} & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{LW} \\
 {$LWMINJ_i$=Largura média das vias de entrada na direcção secundária na intersecção \textit{i} (m)} & {N.A.} &  \\
 \midrule
%%    {$L_i$ =Comprimento total do segento \textit{i} (m)} & {N.A.} & \textit{Shape\_length} & Arcos \\
$MMAJ_i$=Presença de separador central nos dois ramos da direcção principal \textit{i} & {0 - não} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{N.D.} \\
 & {1 - sim} &  \\
  \midrule
%%    $NLANES4_i$=Número total de vias igual ou superior a 4 para o segmento \textit{i} & {0 - não} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{NLANES4} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{Arcos} \\
%%       & {1 - sim} &    &  \\
 $RTPMAJ_i$=Presença de vias exclusivas de viragem à direita na direcção principal na intersecção \textit{i} & {} & \multirow{4}[3]{*}{RTP} \\
 & {0 - não} &   \\
 $RTPMIN_i$=Presença de vias exclusivas de viragem à direita na secundária principal na intersecção \textit{i} & {1 - sim} &   \\
 & {} &  \\
    \midrule
 $TCD_i$=Sistema de controlo de tráfego na intersecção \textit{i} & {0 - não} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{TCD}  \\
  & {1 - sim} &  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}%
   \caption{Variáveis explicativas e atributos correspondentes na \textit{feature class} de nós.}   
  \label{tab:vars}\hspace*{-1cm}%
\end{table}
```

Now, it looks like this, on my thesis --> [image: Almost final big table]

Nevertheless, I think that the line's height is too big, they should be more compact, hence lowering the overall table's height.
What could be an elegant way to do that?

Comment: Perhaps a follow-up question instead of an answer?